# where to add redirection rewriterule in .htaccess file?

Tags: htaccess, redirect

I use the redirection plugin which can give me the rewrite rules in this format as output:

```
# Created by Redirection
# Sun, 06 May 2018 09:25:01 +0000
# Redirection 3.2 - https://redirection.me

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteRule ^abc$ /123/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

# End of Redirection
```

My current .htaccess file is standard:

[image]

Where should I add the direction code from the plugin into the .htaccess file? Should I add it first or last, or somewhere in the existing rule-set?

Thanks!

Comment: @ShameemAliP.K After the closing `</IfModule>` tag? That's exactly where you shouldn't put these directives!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your external redirect needs to go at the very top of your `.htaccess` file, before the WordPress front-controller (ie. before the `# BEGIN WordPress` section).

If you place it at the end of the file then it will simply never get processed, because the WordPress front-controller routes all URLs and then stops further processing.

If you place it inside the `# BEGIN WordPress` block then WordPress is likely to (try to) overwrite this in a future update.

*Aside:* You don't need the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper. You already know that mod_rewrite is enabled on your server (or not) and presumably this redirect is mandatory?